# How would you go about designing your DB to support chain stores?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a data table with thousands of stores. In the beginning I thought it would be a good idea for the store object to have a `parent_id` attribute to group chains stores.

On my website anyone can add a store. There is no routine for adding a "master store". So how then can you select a master store?

So I must find another way to group stores.

I'm thinking og having a separate table where chain stores get a group ID.

The goal is that when you change the description of one store, you can choose to update the description for all stores. This can again be normalized having a separate table for description - but I already have a bunch of tables so I'm not sure if it will have any real gain in normalizing further.

I would like to hear what you think would be the best approach for designing my DB to scale for chain stores.

Comment: Just wondering , basicly , can I add a store and claim to be a part of a stores chain of another member? If you have a confirmation process or something like that - it can be easy to design a DB scale.

Comment: @OfirBaruch - I'm not sure what you mean by `another member`. But all stores must be controlled before made public, so I might as well controll if the selected chain is valid for the store.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field to the `stores table` named `chain` (for instance).
This field will contain some value - integer.
For stores of the same chain there will be the same value,
if there's just one store (not a part of chain) , put a value of 0 (zero).

An example:

> Name | chain
>
> Pizza Hat San-Diego 1
>
> McDonalds Hollywood 2
>
> Pizza Hat London 1
>
> My friend's store 0
>
> McDonalds Spain 2

EDIT:
So when editing Pizza Hat San Diego's store , your script will check for the 'chain' value and if it's different from '0' , your script will update ALL records which their 'chain's field value is 1.

EDIT2: regards **How should the user add it? How should the user select correct ID for new store?**

I guess that in the `stores` table there's also an `owner_id` field which is the id of the member who created this store.
What you can do is to suggest the member , when he's trying to add a new store , chains based on his "adding stores history".

Let's use the example above again:

> Name | Owner ID | chain
>
> Pizza Hat San-Diego | 32 | 1
>
> McDonalds Hollywood | 32 | 2
>
> Pizza Hat London  |32 | 1
>
> My friend's store |43| 0
>
> McDonalds Spain |32| 2

So if the user with the ID 32 is trying to add a new store , you'll show him a dropbox with one of any chains he has: Pizza hat San-diego & McDonalds Hollywood , then you'll ask him "Your new store is related to ...?".

Comment: Yes. It's along the line of what I'm thinking of. But I will still need to add a table to keep controll of the id's. Otherwise the user will never know what ID to select. The table would have the fields `id, name`.

Comment: You don't need a new table for it , just add it as a field to your current stores' table. Or i'm missing something?

Comment: How should the user add it? How should the user select correct ID for new store?